# How to make a title come up when trying to break something you can only break with a specific item?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a horror map and I have signs over a door acting as planks over a door and I already have a set up where you can't break the signs unless you have the item needed.
But how could I add something to where a line of text would pop up saying "You need a crowbar." if you try to break the signs without it?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you want but I have a workaround. Try running this in a repeating command block:

```
/execute at @a[tag=(something to mark that this player hasn't aquired the crowbar)] if block ~~-1~ (block of choice) run /tell @p (text of choice)
```

Then set your block of choice (not the same one as the rest of the floor) in front of the door. Whenever a player walks over this block it will tell them whatever you set the block to say.

Then set a second repeating command block to run:

```
/execute at @a[hasitem={item=(whatever your crowbar item is),location=slot.weapon.mainhand}] run /tag @p remove (whatever tag you selected)
```

so that when a player holds the crowbar they get the tag removed.